# Error installing OpenCV on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-16.04, opencv3.1

I have being trying to install OpenCV on Ubuntu 16.04 unsing several tutorials and i always end up with an error. This is the last one i've got following this tutorial:

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide

What can i do?

```
[ 48%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_viz
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFDefaultStripSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFReadTile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `_TIFFfree@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFTileSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFClientOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFGetFieldDefaulted@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFNumberOfDirectories@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAImage@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFSetWarningHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `_TIFFmalloc@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFSetDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFReadScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImage-6.2.so.6.2: undefined reference to `TIFFNumberOfTiles@LIBTIFF_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/viz/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_viz.dir/build.make:236: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_test_viz' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_viz] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3306: recipe for target 'modules/viz/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_viz.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/viz/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_viz.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: The library for `Tagged Image File Format` (`TIFF`) seems to be missing. You need to install or verify that `libtiff5-dev` is installed. If `libtiff5-dev` doesn't contain the library, you will also need to install `libtiff5`.

Comment: You might want to try [the install-opencv.sh script](http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/). It says its been tested for Ubuntu 16.04 and if you look inside you can see the packages (such as libpng-dev and libtiff5-dev) that it is installing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I followed the same tutorial for install opencv and I had the same problem.
This works for me:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove libtiff5-dev

sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev
```

Enter the opencv directory.

`cd build/` (I guess that is already created,otherwise create it)

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..

make
```

then continue with the tutorial.

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove libtiff5-dev
Warning! Do not do this - it will remove hundreds of packages

Comment: This causes more problems than it solves! As pointed by @Nulldevice hundreds of packages get removed and you end up with a broken system. Especially, all  ROS packages are done away. The answer by user gevang is more sensible.

Answer (score 12):

According to [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/35642/libtiff_40-link-errors/), OpenCV needs `libtiff4`, which Ubuntu has dropped, i.e. the package that replaced it is `libtiff5-dev`.

As a temporary workaround you can specify `-DBUILD_TIFF=ON` on cmake when configuring, in order to build the `libtiff4` version that is distributed with OpenCV.

This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04, with OpenCV 3.2.1.

Comment: This seems to work for me on opencv 3.4.3 on ubuntu 16.04, although it should be `-D BUILD_TIFF=ON`, right?  (missing whitespace)

Comment: This answer works for me on Ubuntu 18.04, and the accepted answer for whatever reason does not. Thanks!

Comment: I used this workaround for OpenCV 4.5 on a newer Ubuntu version now. Can't see the drawback of having OpenCV bring its own version of this lib in my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to install/reinstall libpng.

Comment: I have updeted the error i am geting. Can you plz check it again. I think it has something to do with the fact that i am using libtiff5-dev and it seems to be expecting libtiff4-dev

Answer (score 1):

Try `make clean` ,and then again execute the make command. Generally after one failure if you try the make command without cleaning the earlier installation, you get errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I was building *openCV 3.3.0* together with *opencv_contrib* repository. It turned out that including the flag `-D BUILD_TIFF=ON` with `cmake` command resolved the issue as pointed out by **gevang** already.

Ps.: Since I'm only acknowledging the solution provided by **gevang**, this should rather a be comment instead of an answer, but I'm missing the corresponding rights. Sorry for that.