# Linker Error, Using OpenCV and Eclipse CDT on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I'm going step by step like [this guide](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html) and my code does not compile. It has gotten some linker errors which I don't know how to fix. this is my terminal's answer to : `pkg-config --libs opencv`

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ pkg-config --libs opencv
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so -lopencv_calib3d
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so -lopencv_contrib
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so -lopencv_core
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so -lopencv_features2d
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so -lopencv_flann
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so -lopencv_gpu
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so -lopencv_highgui
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so -lopencv_imgproc
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so -lopencv_legacy
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so -lopencv_ml
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so -lopencv_objdetect
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so -lopencv_ocl
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so -lopencv_photo
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so -lopencv_stitching
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so -lopencv_superres
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so -lopencv_ts
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so -lopencv_video
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so -lopencv_videostab

sorry if it's a mess to read but this is exactly how I received the answer.

This is how I've organized my linker [image: Linker Settings]

this is the error I get:

> > Building target: Ball_Plate Invoking: GCC C++ Linker g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o"Ball_Plate"  ./Src/src.o   -lopencv_core\ opencv_imgproc\ opencv_highgui\ opencv_ml\ opencv_video\ opencv_features2d\ opencv_calib3d\ opencv_objdetect\
> >     opencv_contrib\ opencv_legacy\ opencv_flann /usr/bin/ld: cannot find
> >     -lopencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_ml opencv_video opencv_features2d opencv_calib3d opencv_objdetect opencv_contrib
> >     opencv_legacy opencv_flann collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> >     makefile:45: recipe for target 'Ball_Plate' failed make: ***
> >     [Ball_Plate] Error 1

I don't know how to fix this, I don't know much about how linker works around .so files and I would appreciate that if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

So I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729954/error-installing-opencv-on-ubuntu-16-04) and found out what the problem was, tried to compile the OpenCV library with  `-DBUILD_TIFF=ON`, Now Eclipse can find the header files but I get linker errors again, Eclipse cannot link the libraries.